# how to upload images from web to digital ocean space

Tags: php, digital-ocean

Similar question to someone else but I am trying to upload an image with path_filename like: `https://google.com/example.jpg`

```
use \SpacesAPI\Spaces;

$spaces = new Spaces('api-key', 'api-secret');
$space = $spaces->space('space-name');


$file = $space->uploadFile('http://google.com/example.jpg','example.jpg' );
$file->makePublic();
$fileurl = $file->getURL();
```

my error:

> .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/BucketEndpointArnMiddleware.php(154): Aws\StreamRequestPayloadMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Aws\Command), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))

NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\Exception\IncalculablePayloadException: Payload content length is required and can not be calculated. in .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/StreamRequestPayloadMiddleware.php:71

Comment: What is `$space`, some library object? Please tag library, your `spaces` tag is incorrect. Also you are using digital ocean or AWS/S3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the proper request with the proper arguments.

If you are uploading something from a URL - you first need to get that image's bytes and then use PutObject to upload it to DO spaces

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
2. https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/reference/s3-sdk-examples/#upload-a-file-to-a-space

Comment: Hi Asad, thanks for taking your time to answer. I solved it! :) it had to be saved first but the error was basically telling me that I didn’t have the permission to a folder. Thank you though!